# A trigger to know when there is a new task or updated task?

Tags: asana

I'm working on a chrome extension to have a notification when there is a specific new task. For the moment, the only way to do so is to query every X seconds asana.

Wouldn't it be great to have a trigger url which can be called directly by asana? Or something like that to have real time applications?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: did you find some solution for your problem?

Comment: No. I didn't find such a trigger in the actual API. I hope they will implement one soon... Maybe someone of Asana can answer here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution won't work for a Chrome extension, but may help other people trying to trigger an action when a task changes.

Add a 'dummy' email address as a follower, that is a system email address that is monitored by an application that scans the body of the email to find out which task has been modified.

It is not pretty solution, but may help until Asana gives us some kind of hook.

Regards,
Wayne Wundram